# Simple Usermanagement, Symfony 4 Doctrine Error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I want to create a simple Usermanagement on my Website. I have followed a Tutorial with the Maker-Bundle but if I run the command `doctrine:schema:update --force` I get an Error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT
AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT
NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX
UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':



SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an   
error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   
MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT   
NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX   
UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1
```

And here is my User Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

I have tried several Tutorials but this Error occures everytime, it seems like something with the Datatype of the "roles" field. As it is in some other Tutorials I tried `json_array` and `array` also but again, same Error. 
I'm using a XAMPP Server with MySql Databse on Windows10.

Comment: Might be an error due to MariaDB, just tried with Mysql and it works. Have you tried lauching the query manually ?

Comment: I just tried this `CREATE TABLE 'user' (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB` And now I get this error: `#1064 SQL Syntax... ''user' (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(180) NOT NULL, roles JSON '`

Comment: table name can't be surrounded by `'` (that's for strings), remove them or use backticks ` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of MySQL are you running? JSON data type was introduced in MySQL 5.7.8

XAMPP comes by default with MariaDB, 10.1.37 in the latest version, that doesn't support JSON data types (it will start to do so from version 10.2.6)

You can uninstall MariaDB and install instead MySQL from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
or a more recent version of MariaDB from here https://downloads.mariadb.org/

Comment: The error suggests it is MariaDB (thus and JSON is supported since Maria 10.2) (oh, wrote it just before the edit)

Comment: I'm running version 10.1.31, I try to update it thanks!

Comment: check MariaDB version by typing in phpmyadmin console: select VERSION();

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your mysql version and **make sure it's the same as the one specified in *config/packages/doctrine.yaml***

Json type is not compatible with MySql 5.6 and below and symfony configures with 5.7 by default.

If you're running with 5.6 or less, update config/packages/doctrine.yaml, symfony should take care of the rest.